# WordPress asking for login on public pages on localhost

Tags: login, localhost

I have started learning WordPress custom theme development few weeks ago. I have a WordPress install on my localhost running with XAMPP on Ubuntu 18.04. 
My problem is that when I log out from wp-admin, I can't access public pages on my website (and they are all set to public basically). WordPress just shows a simple log-in form, and it's not even the one with WordPress logo, just basic fields with description. 
Only after I log in, I can browse my website again. 
My other WordPress install (just different folder in the htdocs lampp folder) doesn't have this issue. But I don't know why first one has it, and I couldn't find help on the web.
Any clues?

Comment: Did you check the wordpress directory file permssions?

Comment: Yep. And they're the same as the other project, which is working